# (a) all $13$ spades end up in the same hand?

Tags: probability

Suppose we deal four $13$-card bridge hands from an ordinary $52$-card deck. What
is the probability that

(a) all $13$ spades end up in the same hand? [*]

I'm not understanding this.

(a) $P(\text{how many ways to get 13 spades}) = {13\choose13}$

$P(\text{total number of outcomes}) = {52\choose13}^4$ (idk)

$$P(*) = \frac{1}{{52\choose13}^4} $$

Could someone please explain this to me, thank you.

Comment: The probability that North, say, gets all the spades is $\frac 1{\binom {52}{13}}$.  There are $4$ hands to consider so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(\text{all spades in one hand})=P(\text{all spades in hand }1)+P(\text{all spades in hand }2)+P(\text{all spades in hand }3)+P(\text{all spades in hand }4)=4\cdot P(\text{all spades in hand }1)$$ because all four cases are calculated in exactly the same way and are mutually exclusive.

Now we have
$$P(\text{all spades in hand }1)=\frac{P(\text{how many ways to get 13 spades in hand }1)}{P(\text{total number of outcomes in hand }1)}=\frac{{13\choose13}}{{52\choose13}}=\frac{1}{{52\choose13}},$$
so we end up with
$$P(\text{all spades in one hand})=\frac{4}{{52\choose13}}$$

Comment: The solution is a bit different. $$\frac{4 {39\choose13\text{ }13\text{ }13\text{ }13}}{52\choose{13 \text{ } 13 \text{ } 13} \text{ } 13}$$

Comment: No idea what 52/39 choose 13,13,13,13 even means.

Comment: @hello Definition is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalizations). It's the same result as I have, since all $13!$'s cancel each other out and of course the fact that $\frac{52!}{39!13!}=\frac{52!}{13!39!}$.